# Create list without duplicates automatically

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet

```
           A            B
1         ID           Unique ID
2         27152        27152             
3         27152        29297
4         27152        28802
5         29297
6         29297
7         28802
8         28802
9         28802
10        28802
```

In **Column A** you can find different Product IDs. 
They can appear *several* times in **Column A**.

In **Column B** I want to make a list without the duplicates so 
it shows the unique IDs from the list in **Column A**.

I know I can achieve this by using either the "Advanced Filter" or by the "Remove Duplicate" function unter the tab data tools.

However, I would prefer to create the list in **Column B** without these options since the database in **Column A** will be updated on a regular basis; therefore, it would be better if the multiple values are deleted automatically by a formula in **Column B**.

I was trying to solve it with the AGGREGATE function but could not make it work.

```
B2 =AGGREGATE(14,6,A$2:A$10,1)
B3 =AGGREGATE(14,6,A$2:A$10,2)
B4 =AGGREGATE(14,6,A$2:A$10,3)
```

*Since it should be user-friendly and easy in the handling I would prefer a solution without any array formula or an additional Column that needs to be inserted.*

Comment: Not possible in Excel without array or helper formula. Google Sheets has the UNIQUE function for that https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution for this issue is this new Excel-Formula:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the ID does not matter, here is what you can do

in the first row put the formula

```
C2 =MIN(B2:B10)
```

where `B2:B10` is your ID range

in the next row use this formula

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($B$2:$B$10>C2)*$B$2:$B$10),1)
```

where `C2` is the previous cell(1 row above) here

Drag this formula down until you start getting `#NUM` errors. if you want to get rid of `#NUM` errors, wrap the formula in `IFERROR()`

I saw your comment that you do not want to use Arrays or helper columns. But then Excel isn't magic..... or may be it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF(range; value)` to check how many times your value appears and after that you can just copy your value if `COUNTIF` returns 1

Comment: Hi NikNik, good idea but for this I would need an addtional column that checks each value. My idea is to have one formula that does it in one step without an array or an additional column.

Comment: What about: =IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10; A$2)=1; A$2; ""). What do you mean with "without an array"?

Answer (score 0):

You can user a macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterUnique()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("B2"), _
    Unique:=True

End Sub
```

As others have said - it is impossible to do it without adding a column or using a filter, macro or array

Answer (score 0):

Arguably a PivotTable would produce such a list "automatically" though PT would need to be refreshed if entries are added to ColumnA (plus perhaps a once-off change of label, sorting and Conditional Formatting to 'hide' `(blank)`, if required).